# How can i configure Openstack Swift with multiple storage nodes

Tags: cloud, storage, hardware, openstack, openstack-swift

I have two IBM X3650M4 Servers with 8GB RAM in each. totally i have 3.2TB External storage.
I want to implement storage service using openstack swift. can you please tell me, how to configure the existing hardware into proxy and storage nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit open..I recommend that you start reading swift documentation:
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/

You should first understand the concepts of rings, accounts, containers, objects,etc, and how swift works in general.

Try first with a local environment, two virtual box machines would be enough.

But answering your question, and saying you just have two nodes...a logical set up would be to have one proxy and storage node in one server, and the other just a storage node..

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack has a detailed explanation on how to install and configure swift. http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/howto_installmultinode.html

However you should definitely understand the concepts, because you will have to tune the configurations based on your needs and configuration.